# can't access to custom property that set to header in transformer - spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have these channel and transformer.

```
<integration:channel id="channel">
<integration:interceptors>
        <integration:wire-tap channel="logChannel"/>
    </integration:interceptors>
</integration:channel>
<integration:transformer input-channel="channel"
                         output-channel="resultChannel"
                         ref="transformerImpl"
                         method="transform">
</integration:transformer>
```

In transformer, I couldn't access to my custom property in header by @Header. but in logChannel, i log my headers, and everything is ok. my property is exist. any idea ?

Comment: Could you show the method "transfrom" where you try to access headers?

Comment: in my transfomr method i use this in as argument : @Header(value = "sampleId", required = false) Long sampleId.
when i get default headers like jms_timestap, everything is ok but i can't get my custome property in header

Comment: Show the code of that `transform()` method. And also show log for message which is sent to the `channel`.

Answer (score 0):

In the Framework we have a couple test-cases for similar approach:

```
    @Transformer
    public String headerTest(String s, @Header("number") Integer num) {
        return s + num;
    }

    @Transformer
    public String optionalHeaderTest(String s, @Header(value = "number", required = false) Integer num) {
        return s + num;
    }
```

The tests for `optionalHeaderTest` transformer look like:

```
@Test
public void optionalHeaderAnnotation() throws Exception {
    TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
    Method testMethod = testBean.getClass().getMethod("optionalHeaderTest", String.class, Integer.class);
    MethodInvokingTransformer transformer = new MethodInvokingTransformer(testBean, testMethod);
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo").setHeader("number", 99).build();
    Message<?> result = transformer.transform(message);
    assertEquals("foo99", result.getPayload());
}

@Test
public void optionalHeaderValueNotProvided() throws Exception {
    TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
    Method testMethod = testBean.getClass().getMethod("optionalHeaderTest", String.class, Integer.class);
    MethodInvokingTransformer transformer = new MethodInvokingTransformer(testBean, testMethod);
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo").build();
    Message<?> result = transformer.transform(message);
    assertEquals("foonull", result.getPayload());
}
```

Can you check what message have adding to your `transform()` the whole `Message<?>` object? This way you have access to all the headers.